# How do I set the default value for TAX for all products?

Tags: magento-1.9

In Magento 1 I want to set the VAT to default value for all products.

I put an image below to understand exactly what I am referring to.

https://ibb.co/fiu8Ro

Is there an option for this or should I modify somewhere in a module this?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the tax class for all products in three ways:

1. By mass action in product grid in admin
2. By custom script on root to update the tax_class_id attribute
3. By direct SQL query in database

All the ways are mentioned in below article.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17735/magento-applying-tax-class-to-all-products